# How can my ANTLR parser (not lexer) trigger a lexical "include" (not AST splice)?

Tags: c#, include, antlr, antlr3

The ANTLR website describes [two approaches](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557057) to implementing "include" directives. The first approach is to recognize the directive in the lexer and include the file lexically (by pushing the CharStream onto a stack and replacing it with one that reads the new file); the second is to recognize the directive in the parser, launch a sub-parser to parse the new file, and splice in the AST generated by the sub-parser. Neither of these are quite what I need.

In the language I'm parsing, recognizing the directive in the lexer is impractical for a few reasons:

1. There is no self-contained character pattern that always means "this is an include directive". For example, `Include "foo";` at top level is an include directive, but in `Array bar --> Include "foo";` or `Constant Include "foo";` the word `Include` is an identifier.
2. The name of the file to include may be given as a string or as a constant identifier, and such constants can be defined with arbitrarily complex expressions.

So I want to trigger the inclusion from the parser. But to perform the inclusion, I can't launch a sub-parser and splice the AST together; I have to splice the tokens. It's legal for a block to begin with `{` in the main file and be terminated by `}` in the included file. A file included inside a function can even close the function definition and start a new one.

It seems like I'll need something like the first approach but at the level of TokenStreams instead of CharStreams. Is that a viable approach? How much state would I need to keep on the stack, and how would I make the parser switch back to the original token stream instead of terminating when it hits EOF? Or is there a better way to handle this?

==========

Here's an example of the language, demonstrating that blocks opened in the main file can be closed in the included file (and vice versa). Note that the `#` before `Include` is required when the directive is inside a function, but optional outside.

main.inf:

```
[ Main;
  print "This is Main!";
  if (0) {
  #include "other.h";
  print "This is OtherFunction!";
];
```

other.h:

```
  } ! end if
];  ! end Main

[ OtherFunction;
```

Comment: Is this a language designed for masochists?

Comment: Heh. This is Inform, a language for writing text adventure games. The English-like Inform 7 (http://inform7.com) is an example of the elegant and awesome things you can do when your design isn't constrained by traditional context-free parsing tools. Unfortunately, I'm parsing Inform 6, which is an example of the unspeakably *awful* things you can do when your design isn't constrained by traditional context-free parsing tools.

Comment: @BartKiers Luckily, no: the filename can only be a quoted string or a single identifier that was defined earlier with `Constant`. The definition given to `Constant` has to be a compile-time constant, so no function calls. The language also has no text operators, so no concatenation, but it can duplicate another constant: `Constant FOO "file.h"; Constant BAR FOO; Include BAR;`

Comment: But the `Constant` directive in general can have arbitrarily complex expressions since it's usually used with numbers: `Constant FOO (BAR + 5 * BAZ);` etc., so handling `Constant` in the lexer is impractical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is for each `Include` statement to let your parser create a new instance of your lexer and insert these new tokens the lexer creates at the index the parser is currently at (see the `insertTokens(...)` method in the parser's `@members` block.).

Here's a quick demo:

### Inform6.g

```
grammar Inform6;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  STATS;
  F_DECL;
  F_CALL;
  EXPRS;
}

@parser::header {
  import java.util.Map;
  import java.util.HashMap;
}

@parser::members {
  private Map<String, String> memory = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

  private void putInMemory(String key, String str) {
    String value;
    if(str.startsWith("\"")) {
      value = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
    }
    else {
      value = memory.get(str);
    }
    memory.put(key, value);
  }

  private void insertTokens(String fileName) {
    // possibly strip quotes from `fileName` in case it's a Str-token
    try {
      CommonTokenStream thatStream = new CommonTokenStream(new Inform6Lexer(new ANTLRFileStream(fileName)));
      thatStream.fill();
      List extraTokens = thatStream.getTokens();
      extraTokens.remove(extraTokens.size() - 1); // remove EOF
      CommonTokenStream thisStream = (CommonTokenStream)this.getTokenStream();
      thisStream.getTokens().addAll(thisStream.index(), extraTokens);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

parse
 : stats EOF -> stats
 ;

stats
 : stat* -> ^(STATS stat*)
 ;

stat
 : function_decl
 | function_call
 | include
 | constant
 | if_stat
 ;

if_stat
 : If '(' expr ')' '{' stats '}' -> ^(If expr stats)
 ;

function_decl
 : '[' id ';' stats ']' ';' -> ^(F_DECL id stats)
 ;

function_call
 : Id exprs ';' -> ^(F_CALL Id exprs)
 ;

include
 : Include Str ';' {insertTokens($Str.text);}            -> /* omit statement from AST */
 | Include id ';'  {insertTokens(memory.get($id.text));} -> /* omit statement from AST */
 ;

constant
 : Constant id expr ';' {putInMemory($id.text, $expr.text);} -> ^(Constant id expr)
 ;

exprs
 : expr (',' expr)* -> ^(EXPRS expr+)
 ;

expr
 : add_expr
 ;

add_expr
 : mult_expr (('+' | '-')^ mult_expr)*
 ;

mult_expr
 : atom (('*' | '/')^ atom)*
 ;

atom
 : id
 | Num
 | Str
 | '(' expr ')' -> expr
 ;

id
 : Id
 | Include
 ;

Comment  : '!' ~('\r' | '\n')* {skip();};
Space    : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
If       : 'if';
Include  : 'Include';
Constant : 'Constant';
Id       : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')+;
Str      : '"' ~'"'* '"';
Num      : '0'..'9'+ ('.' '0'..'9'+)?;
```

### main.inf

```
Constant IMPORT "other.h";

[ Main;
  print "This is Main!";
  if (0) {    

  Include IMPORT;

  print "This is OtherFunction!";
];
```

### other.h

```
  } ! end if
];  ! end Main

[ OtherFunction;
```

### Main.java

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create lexer & parser
    Inform6Lexer lexer = new Inform6Lexer(new ANTLRFileStream("main.inf"));
    Inform6Parser parser = new Inform6Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

    // print the AST
    DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
    StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT((CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree());
    System.out.println(st);
  }
}
```

To run the demo, do the following on the command line:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool Inform6.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
```

The output you'll see corresponds to the following AST:

[image]